# Downloaded Image Appears very blurry

Tags: android

I downloaded an image to use following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/) excellent article. My own image I'm using is a google map static image that is 300x400. I've fiddle with a few of the settings and have expanded it to fill across the screen, however it just appears very blurry.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="0dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

That is what I have in the screen xml layout. Is this a common problem? I did a good search and couldn't find an answer. Is 300x400 not a good res for android?

Comment: Keep in mind most phone screens are at least 480x800 pixels (and 720x1280 is becoming quite common). Even taking pixel-density into account, your image is probably getting scaled up.

Comment: I tried it with a really high res picture and that too is distorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason why they were low, the image loader class had a built in compression:

```
//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

So just remove this part so you are left with:

```
//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){

  try {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;

}
```

Crystal clear images.

Comment: this give following error on multiple images use ........ 4147200-byte external allocation too large for this process.

Comment: Very bad answer. You have removed downsampling and like @The Ray of Hope said, you are now risking OOM issues.

Answer (score 1):

> Is 300x400 not a good res for android?

it depends on original image orientation and a couple of other things like your layout and device display. Alternatively, you could try the following code to download an image, this works fine for me:

don't forget to add

```
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

to your Manifest

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button get;
private ImageView pic;
private static final String SRC = "http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    get = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    pic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    get.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pic.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(SRC));

        }
    });

}

 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("getBmpFromUrl error: ", e.getMessage().toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried this and got a force close. Do you have the code you use to set the image. I'm using:

        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg");
             img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: I updated my answer. Please note that setting the OnClickListener is usually done in the onResume() method, the code above is just a basic example