# how to display .jpg image in android?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, file-format, android-file

I am using .net web services and I am having list of folders and files. I am successful in retrieving list of files(.jpg Image, .pdf, .TIF) but can anybody let me know how we can open .jpg, .pdf, .tif or other files format which I am getting from web services. Is there any specific code to open particular format or we can use path (/) to open that particular file?

Thanks.

Comment: Your can use ImageView for displaying .jpg image

Comment: okay, Means I need to use different layouts to display particular picture in that layout using ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to download and display an image, check my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945948/downloaded-image-appears-very-blurry/14946081#14946081) post, that is probably what you are looking for. Common extensions for displaying images in Android are .png and .jpeg, you will not be able to show a .pdf file using an `ImageView`. You can also use the method mentioned in my answer inside an `AsyncTask` to perform the download in background and then update your UI thread

Comment: Hi @ Maver1ck, thanks for your link. I am trying to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @ Maver1ck, I am not able to understand ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt; data;
public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt; d) {
HashMap&lt;String, String&gt; song = new HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;();
        song = data.get(position); I dn;t know what it is exactly.

Comment: I am trying to use http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ this link